# Styling issue - CSS Ignoring white-space: nowrap;

Tags: html, css

I have some text inside a div which is set to a fixed width.

I want the div to expand and retract vertically depending on the length of text.

I have turned off `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow: hidden;` which wraps the text onto a second line as I want it to, but it doesn't vertically expand the containing div box and make the price underneith move further down, it instead overlaps it.

My code below is a simplified version of what I want it to do - which works.

However my attached image shows the real website in Inspector that I cannot get to work. Could there be some code elsewhere I need to change?

```css
 .product-item--info {
  width: 100px;
 }


 .product-title {
  padding: 2px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  /*toggling this on and off shows what I want my real example to do*/
  /*white-space: nowrap;*/
    
     text-overflow:ellipsis;
 }
```

```html
    <div class="product-item--info">

     <h2 class="product-title" itemprop="model">
         <a href="https://proco.infigosoftware.com/villagepos/p/496/extra-bank-holiday-savings-50x40">Extra Bank Holiday Savings 50x40</a>
     </h2>

  <br>

     <div class="alternate--prices">
         <span class="productPrice">0.00</span>
     </div>

  <br>

     <div class="description" itemprop="description">
         FV001776
     </div>

  <br>

        <div class="product--stockquantity">
   Stock: 50
  </div>


 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: How do you expect it to expand when you set a fixed width?

Comment: @OnlineUser02094 I want it to expand and retract vertically

Comment: you either have set a fixed height on the title or you have positioned it absolutely - either way, you have not created a [mcve] therefore this question is off topic and I vote to close

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
.product-item--info {
  width: auto;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
    }


.product-title {
    padding: 2px 0px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

background red just so you can see the width of the div.

With this, the div is whatever length the text is with the padding already set. If I remove some characters from the header to make it smaller, the div also sets to that width.

Answer (score 0):

As Pete was pointing out, your product-title is positioned as absolute, which gets it out of the flow so you would also need to reposition the prices.